# getting first time total is fine, but when changing the discount or quantity will give incorrect result

Tags: javascript, jquery

- when the quantity or discount change, getting item total price is fine
  (*calculateItemTotal()* function is defined in both input fields to capture the value and based on that giving me the item total value)
- based on number of rows adding, the item total calculation is working correctly and **adding the all item total** and **display in the total text field**
- **first time around summation of all item total getting correct value** to the total text field.
- after getting total value, **if I changed the quantity or discount field** **total text field** giving me **incorrect value.**

---

### html page total text field markup

```html
<label class="control-label col-xs-5">Total: </label>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <input type="text" name="totalprice" id="finaltotalprice" class="form-control" disabled> <!-- final total value is here -->
  </div>
```

---

### JavaScript/jQuery function for dynamically adding rows

*there in no error in executing this bit of code*

```js
// dynamically changing the row id for table rows
let rowId = 0;

$("#soid").change(function() {
 $.get("../ajax/ajax_product.php?type=get_sales_order_list", {salesOrderId: $("#soid").val()} , function (data) {
  if(data) {
     console.log(data);
     let orderItems = JSON.parse(data);
     console.log(orderItems);
     $("#sales_item_list").html('');

      for(let list in orderItems) {
          $("#sales_item_list").append("<tr>" + 
          "<td><input type='text' name='quantity[]' class='form-control' id='quantity_"+ rowId +"' value='"+ orderItems[list].sales_list_item_quantity +"' onchange='calculateItemTotal("+ rowId +")' ></td>"+ 
          "<td><input type='hidden' name='unitprice[]' id='unitprice_"+ rowId +"' class='form-control' value='"+ orderItems[list].unit_price +"' readonly>"+ orderItems[list].unit_price +"</td>" + 
          "<td><input type='text' name='discount[]' class='form-control'  id='discount_"+ rowId +"' onchange='calculateItemTotal("+ rowId +")'></td>" + 
          "<td><input type='text' name='itemtotalprice[]' class='form-control' id='itemtot_"+ rowId +"' ></td>"  + 
          "</tr>");
   rowId++;
                }
            }

        });
    });
```

---

### calculateItemTotal() function

```js
    let finalTot = 0;
    function calculateItemTotal(data) {
        let quantity = parseInt($("#quantity_"+data).val()); // take the quantity value to quantity variable -- ok
        if(isNaN(quantity)) quantity = 0; // make it 0 if it is not a number

        let unitPrice = parseFloat($("#unitprice_"+data).val()); // take the unit price value to the unit price variable --ok
        if(isNaN(unitPrice)) unitPrice = 0.00;

        let tot = quantity * unitPrice; // calculation is ok
        let discount = (parseFloat($("#discount_"+data).val())/100 * tot).toFixed(2); // calculation is ok
        if(isNaN(discount)) discount = 0.00;

        let net_total = tot - discount; // this is also ok

        let with2Decimals = parseFloat(net_total).toFixed(2); // this is also ok

        $("#itemtot_"+data).val(with2Decimals); // set the calculated price of product item -- ok

        // this is also ok
        let convertToNumber = parseFloat($("#itemtot_"+data).val());

        putFinalTotal(convertToNumber); // calling for the function to set the final total, -- ok
    }
    
    
function putFinalTotal(convertToNumber) {
   finalTot = finalTot + convertToNumber;
   console.log(typeof(finalTot));
   $("#finaltotalprice").val(finalTot.toFixed(2)); // set the total value to the "total" text field
}
```

---

### first time calculation

correctly adding the item totals

[image]

---

### when ever if I changed quantity or discount, total value gives me incorrect value

ex:- I changed quantity from 10 to 100, gives me correct item total but incorrect total value

*correct answer should be 14400 but gives me 15600*

[image]

can please someone can give me insight, how to figure out this issue.

Comment: Please combine your snippets into a single snippet that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subtract **Item total price** before a new sum because its current value is saved in **finalTot**.

Try:

```
let finalTot = 0;

function calculateItemTotal( data ) {
    const rowTotalElement = $( '#itemtot_' + data );
    const currentRowTotal = parseFloat( rowTotalElement.val() );
    if ( !isNaN( currentRowTotal ) ) {
        finalTot -= currentRowTotal;
    }

    let quantity = parseInt( $( '#quantity_' + data ).val() ); // take the quantity value to quantity variable -- ok
    if ( isNaN( quantity ) ) {
        quantity = 0;
    } // make it 0 if it is not a number

    let unitPrice = parseFloat( $( '#unitprice_' + data ).val() ); // take the unit price value to the unit price variable --ok
    if ( isNaN( unitPrice ) ) {
        unitPrice = 0.00;
    }

    let tot = quantity * unitPrice; // calculation is ok
    let discount = (parseFloat( $( '#discount_' + data ).val() ) / 100 * tot).toFixed( 2 ); // calculation is ok
    if ( isNaN( discount ) ) {
        discount = 0.00;
    }

    let net_total = tot - discount; // this is also ok

    let with2Decimals = parseFloat( net_total ).toFixed( 2 ); // this is also ok

    rowTotalElement.val( with2Decimals ); // set the calculated price of product item -- ok

    // this is also ok
    let convertToNumber = parseFloat( rowTotalElement.val() );

    putFinalTotal( convertToNumber ); // calling for the function to set the final total, -- ok
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but it shows the "NaN" in the total text field value.